# Need to refer to second to the last element of array of partial filenames

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

I need to find distinct values of partial filenames in an array of filenames. I'd like to do it in one line.
So, I have something like that as a filenames:

```
string[] filenames = {"aaa_ab12345.txt", "bbb_ab12345.txt", "aaa_ac12345.txt", "bbb_ac12345"}
```

and I need to find distinct values for ab12345 part of it.
So I currently have something like that:

```
string[] filenames_partial_distinct = Array.ConvertAll(
        filenames,
        file => System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
            .Split({"_","."}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]
)
.Distinct()
.ToArray();
```

Now, I'm getting filenames that are of form of aaa_bbb_ab12345.txt. So, instead of referring to the second part of the filename, I need to refer to the second to the last.
So, how do I refer to an arbitrary element based on length of array in one line, if it's a result of Split method? Something along lines of:

```
Array.ConvertAll(filenames, file=>file.Split(separator)[this.Length-2]).Distinct().ToArray();
```

In other words, if a string method results in an array of strings, how do I immediately select element based on the length of array:

```
String.Split()[third from end, fifth from end, etc.];
```

Comment: The second code block is invalid... Please update so we can help you further.

Comment: Can you give a more concise example of your expected input set(s) and your expected results.

Comment: The new ranges/indices in C# 8 would work well here `[^2]` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges

Comment: In this string: `{"aaa_ab12345.txt", "bbb_ab12345.txt", "aaa_ac12345.txt", "bbb_ac12345", "aaa_bbb_ab12345.txt", "aaa_ccc_ab12345.txt", "aaa_bbb_ac12345.txt", "aaa_ccc_ac12345.txt"}` I need to find distinct values of that part that consists of two letters and four numbers. It always goes the last before ".txt"

Comment: "I'd like to do it one line". Please curb that desire, if you value the mental health of those programmers who have to maintain your code later.

Comment: `var q = filenames.Select(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).Split('_').Last()).Distinct().ToArray();`

Answer (score 3):

If you use `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` there will be no extension and therefore splitting by `'_'` will do it. Then you can take the last part with `.Last()`.

```
string[] filenames_partial_distinct = Array.ConvertAll(
        filenames,
        file => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).Split('_').Last()
    )
    .Distinct()
    .ToArray();
```

With the input

```
string[] filenames = { "aaa_ab12345.txt", "bbb_ab12345.txt",
    "aaa_ac12345.txt", "bbb_ac12345", "aaa_bbb_ab12345.txt" };
```

You get the result

```
{ "ab12345", "ac12345" }
```

The `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` is only required if there are filenames ending with `_` (before the extension).

Comment: Simple, clean, and a refreshing lack of backslashes.  As a professor I had once said, "Regex is great, and should be avoided when possible."

Comment: This will fail for `bbb_ac12345`. They apparently all don't have the '.txt' extension from the question.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata, No, it will not fail, as `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` removes the extension and the dot anyway. Therefore `Split` gets always the same input without extension. This code is tested and works (see the two last code snippets).

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're looking for something like this:

```
string[] arr = filenames.Select(n => n.Substring(n.IndexOf("_") + 1, 7)).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually defer problems like this to [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8). They are very powerful. This approach also gives you the opportunity to detect unexpected cases and handle them appropriately.

Here is a crude example, assuming I understood your requirements:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()       
    {
        string MyMatcher(string filename)
        {
           // this pattern may need work depending on what you need - it says
           // extract that pattern between the "()" which is 2 characters and
           // 4 digits, exactly; and can be found in `Groups[1]`.
           Regex r = new Regex(@".*_(\w{2}\d{4}).*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
           Match m = r.Match(filename);
           return m.Success
               ? m.Groups[1].ToString()
               : null; // what should happen here? 
        }

        string[] filenames = 
        {
            "aaa_ab12345.txt",
            "bbb_ab12345.txt",
            "aaa_ac12345.txt",
            "bbb_ac12345",
            "aaa_bbb_ab12345.txt",
            "ae12345.txt" // MyMatcher() return null for this - what should you do if this happens?
        };

        var results = filenames
            .Select(MyMatcher)
            .Distinct();

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Gives:

```
ab1234
ac1234
```

This can be refined further, such as pre-compiled regex patterns, encapsulation in a class, etc.